# What is the best source for statistics on disability?

Tags: research, musculoskeletal-system

I'm doing some research into fine motor disabilities, and I'm having trouble finding comprehensive sources. In essence, I'm looking for statistics on disorders or conditions which impede the use of fine motor skills in the hands and fingers. My focus would primarily be on teens or adults, but inclusive sources would work too. Searching for "fine motor disability" doesn't yield much of use and neither does searching on google scholar or Statistia. Of course, I don't need information on every conceivable disorder, but I'd like to be able to gather enough data such that I can report that "approximately xx% of people in the U.S suffer from a fine motor disability which affects the use of their hands." Does anyone know where I should look for information like this? Any clarifying questions are welcome, and if this is the wrong place for this, let me know and I'll move it.

Comment: Have you tried using pubmed? Do you have any specific fine motor disability in mind?